# The meanings of some symbols in "Calculus of variations"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Could someone tell me the meanings of the "C" and its superscript "1" and subscript "0" in the equation which I have marked.

[image]

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Added your image...

Comment: $C^1[a,b]$ is the set of functions that admit a continuously differentiable extension to an open set containing $[a,b]$. (As of the notation **I** know; I don't and I can't know if your book said anything different)

Answer (score 0):

A function is in $C[a,b]$ (also written $C^{0}[a,b]$) if it is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$. A function is in $C^{n}[a,b]$ if it has $n$ derivatives, all continuous. The interval can be omitted if one means all of whatever set one is writing about. For example, $|x|$ is in $C^{0}$ because it is a continuous function, but $|x|\not\in C^{1}$ because its derivative is not continuous. Sometimes $C^{\infty}$ is written to denote infinitely smooth/differentiable functions.  The $0$ subscript can mean different things in different texts, but I often see it mean that the functions in the set have boundary conditions equal to 0 on the first $n-1$ derivatives, including the original function.